# Generics: Where T is TypeA OR TypeB

Tags: c#, generics

When dealing with generics we can do `where T: TypeA, TypeB` which means T must be implementing both TypeA and TypeB. But is it possible to use an OR in this expression? For example `where T: TypeA || TypeB` ? is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you make `TypeA` and `TypeB` inherit/implement a parent class/interface?

Comment: @DavidG: no for example `Where T: Label OR TextBlock`, and not using the Control class for some reason.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning here that `Label` and `TextBlock` inherit from [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx) so you could use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not possible and it wouldn't really make sense. You could never rely on `T` having certain members available because it could be A *or* B. All members are optional then.

It certainly is conceivable to have this feature but it goes against the spirit of generics. This would only be useful in a reflection situation.

Answer (score 7):

The only way to achieve this would be to make `TypeA` and `TypeB` inherit or implement the same parent class or interface. For example:

```
public interface IParent
{
}

public class TypeA : IParent
{
    //snip
}

public class TypeB : IParent
{
    //snip
}
```

Then you can use

```
public class Blah<T> where T: IParent
{
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is sometimes the Type is SEALED, and I can't inherit that and implement the IParent interface on it.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying that this is the only way to achieve what you want.

Comment: You can always wrap around a sealed class, to some extent.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: In theory yes, but in practice there are situations where you can't. I agree that wrapping certain types, specially when dealing with external libraries is a good practice to prevent problems such as when a type becomes obsolete, but sometimes things are more complicated than we expect.